# Как сравнить несколько значений из одной таблицы с несколькими значениями из другой?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, даже не знаю, с какой стороны к ней подойти. У меня есть две таблицы, я достаю по определённому критерию несколько значений из одной таблицы и, аналогичным образом, несколько значений из другой. Мне нужно сравнить между собой эти две группы, чтобы получить финальную выборку. Приведу простой пример. Допустим, первая таблица включает в себя мировые столицы с указанием численности населения, а вторая - страны с указанием континентов, на которых они находятся, и с перечислением разной информации по стране в отдельной строке (там же есть и столица). Мне надо найти **айдишники** всех южноамериканских столиц-миллионников. Вот пример, как всё выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первой таблице я сортирую все города по численности населения; во второй таблице я сортирую все страны по Южной Америке и в строке с городами методом substring достаю название столицы. По отдельности оба запроса, конечно же, работают. Теперь мне нужно сравнить столицы-миллионники из первого запроса с южноамериканскими столицами из второго запроса. Я ставлю оба запроса в скобки и сравниваю через оператор LIKE. Вопрос по типу **select ID from Table1 where (Query1) like (Query2)**

В результате получаю такую ошибку: SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Я понимаю, что ошибка возникает из-за того, что я пытаюсь сравнить сразу много значений со многими значениями; по идее, нужно написать цикл, чтобы первое значение сравнивалось со всеми из второго запроса, потом второе и т.д. Если моя догадка верна, можете подсказать, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: нужно не писать циклы, сравнивать подстроки через лайк или еще как-то, а нормализовать данные. БД это не просто две таблицы, в которые можно напихать всякого мусора, это - структура. У вас должны быть таблицы городов, стран, континентов. У городов должны быть проставлены принадлежность к стране,и, например, флаг, столица это или нет. У стран должна быть проставлена принадлежность к континентам (принадлежность - в данном случае это столбец в внешним ключом). При такой структуризации запрос будет элементарно решаться с `join+where`

Comment: Если убрать то, что в Южной Америке нет Франции с США, то запрос должен выглядеть примерно так: `select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.информация like '%t1.город%'` и между % надо добавить символы конкатенации вашей субд

Comment: @SwaD, большое спасибо за Ваш ответ. Я попробовал так сделать, как Вы советуете. И даже немного разобрался со своим невежеством, чтобы достать название города из колонки "информация" без substring - информация там в формате jsonb. Я также убрал одно из условий, чтобы запрос был попроще (чтобы посмотреть, будет ли так работать) - получается запрос:
select ID from table1 join table2 on table1.город like (select информация ->> 'city' from table2 where континент = "Южная Америка").

Результат всё тот же: SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression :(

Comment: @teran, благодарю Вас за Ваш развёрнутый ответ, однако - к сожалению или счастью - не я делал БД и не мне её править. Я работаю с тем, что есть. Пример с городами и странами, конечно же, просто чтобы не публиковать здесь реальные данные, по которым нужна выборка. Ваши ценные советы я обязательно учту на будущее, если когда-то буду создавать БД самостоятельно. А сейчас мне просто нужно выполнить нужный запрос.

Comment: Приведите в виде текста примеры данных в двух таблицах и можно будет подсказать вариант. Пока ваши данные не удобны и дадут пустой ответ  на ваш же вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментариям, скорее всего вы пытаетесь соединить две таблицы путем сравнения одной строки со столбца [Город] со всем набором данных полученной из подзапроса. Ошибка `SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` вполне обоснована.

Нужно чутка изменить соединение таблиц чтобы сравнение происходило поле [Город] с полем из подзапроса, например [Столица]. Выглядеть это будет как-то так:

```
  SELECT
    c.*
  FROM
    cities c
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        BTRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(Информация, ';', 1), ':', 2)) AS Столица
      FROM countries
      WHERE
        Континент = 'Евразия'
    ) t ON t.Столица = c.Город
```

Ну или через функцию EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  cities c
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          BTRIM(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(Информация, ';', 1), ':', 2)) AS Столица
        FROM countries
        WHERE
          Континент = 'Евразия'
      ) t
    WHERE
      c.Город = t.Столица
  )
```

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ, в итоге проблему решила функция EXISTS.